# No interactive widgets is getting displayed in chrome browser while running ipynb file using Voila

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I am trying to run my ipynb file using voila, which have some interactive widgets and plots. I am using voila (0.1.21), to create a dashboard application. When i am opening the application (http://localhost:8866) in chrome browser, it does not display any of interactive widgets. I am running on mac.

When I am running in Notebook (6.0.3) ,all interactive widgets and plots are displaying without any issue.

Following is the one of code :

```
@interact
def show_articles_more_than(column=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width'], x=(-2, 20, .1)):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(HTML(f'<h2>Showing data with more than {x} {column}<h2>'))
    display(iris.loc[iris[column] > x, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'class']])
```

Getting following error:

```
    Starting WebSocket: ws://localhost:8866/api/kernels/72f234eb-f69b-4244-a8de-2beac4588296
manager.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'kernelChanged' of undefined
    at new M (manager.js:61)
    at new t.WidgetManager (manager.js:47)
    at main.js:14
default.js:1452 Kernel: connected (72f234eb-f69b-4244-a8de-2beac4588296)
```

My NB extension list :

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /Users/adhishree/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
  config dir: /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      bqplot/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      ipyvolume/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-webrtc/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-datawidgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-threejs/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      plotlywidget/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      voila/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

Can anyone help me on how the interactive widgets can be displayed properly in the chrome browser.

Comment: Just a guess: I think Voila cannot render one element, because of this a property is undefined. Try to find the problematic element.

Comment: Voila able to render all widgets when I open it in Safari, but not working in chrome.
I upgraded the chrome also. now getting following error along with previous error also.
GET http://localhost:8866/voila/files/favicon.ico 403 (Forbidden)